# Update directive content and events after click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

now; I'm making a directive to add/remove an article as a favourite (a user has a list of favourite articles), it displays a full/empty heart icon depending if the article is already a favourite or not, and when the user clicks on it, it favorite/unfavourite the article (and changes it's behavior to undo the fav action).

```
function favouriteWidgetDirective($rootScope, articles) {
    return {
      scope: {
        'article': '='
      },
      restrict: 'A',
      template: '<button class="favourite" >' +
                    '<i class="icon-heart-{{ favClass }}" ng-click="favFunction(article.id)"></i>' +
                '</button>',
      link: function postLink($scope, element, attrs) {

        //Check if an article is already a favorite, uses the favourites array of the logged user
        var isFavourite = function(id) {
          var favourite = false;
          $rootScope.currentUser.favourites.some(function (fav, idx) {
            if (fav.article === id) {
              favourite = true;
              return true;
            }
          });
          return favourite;
        };

        var setFavourite = function(id) {
          event.stopPropagation();
          //API call
          articles.favourite(id);
          //Update user favourites array
          $rootScope.currentUser.favourites.push({article: id});
          //Some magic here to update the icon and the click binding??
          //....
        };

        var unFavourite = function(id) {
          //Very similar to setFavourite.., but the opposite
        };

        var articleIsFavourite = isFavourite($scope.article.id);
        //The style for the button (an empty or full heart)
        $scope.favClass = articleIsFavourite ? 'full' : 'empty';
        //The function that will be used on the click
        $scope.favFunction = articleIsFavourite ? unFavourite : setFavourite;

      }
    };
  }
```

Now the problem (that for the trained eye must be obvious at this point), the API gets called and the fav added, but the UI is not updating itself with the new class or the new function.

I've read that Angular is great but not magic, and I need to add an $apply or a $watch, but since I don't master these techniques I havn't been able to get the desired behavior.

The current aproach is very open to changes (since as a begginer with directives this could be really wrong, I know), so if it has to be throwed away and rebuilt just let me know (kindly :), adding suggestions).

Thank you.

Comment: You already set `favClass` and `favFunction`, so you know how to do it. I'm not sure where you see the problem.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that, I was so deeply focused on the wrong spot that missed it. Now, added the lines to set those two variables and it worked, last question would be; is this the recomended way of doing it? (I always try to do things in the most accepted way so they can be understood by anyone, and criticized by few)

Comment: There's nothing inherently wrong with this approach. You might take a look at the `ngClass` directive. That way you wouldn't have to set the `favClass`.